# Adjust height of <mat-form-field> in Angular 17

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I am using Angular 17 with `Angular Material 17.2.2`. I want to adjust the height of the `<mat-form-field>` tag to make it smaller. I am able to resize the tag, but I am not able to resize the placeholder inside.

I have tried adjusting the height and its working but the placeholder is not resizing

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="height: 40px; padding-top: 10px;">
 <input matInput placeholder="Enter name">
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your code into this stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-17-file-upload-a8kgxv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Finput%2Finput.component.html 
so that we can take a look try to help you.

Comment: it's **discouraged** to modify the Material design components.
if you really want to do it, you can add a class to your `mat-form-field` and then in the global `styles.scss` you can do the changes you want, including the placeholder position